# Golang Docker SDK : Pushing large image into remote registry failing

Tags: docker, go, docker-registry, moby

Im having hard time understanding how image push works

```
var authConfig = types.AuthConfig{
    Username:      "amokkara",
    Password:      "dummy",
    ServerAddress: "https://docker.repo.dummy.dummy.com",
}

ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*120)
defer cancel()

authConfigBytes, _ := json.Marshal(authConfig)
authConfigEncoded := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(authConfigBytes)
opts := types.ImagePushOptions{RegistryAuth: authConfigEncoded}
ioreader , err := dockerClient.ImagePush(ctx,"docker.repo.dummy.dummy.com/amokkara/ads-nodeinfo- 
    controller:test",opts)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
    defer ioreader.close()
io.Copy(os.Stdout, ioreader)

return nil
```

Im trying to push large image to remote registry (~500 mb)
How to know when image is pushed?
And in my case, im getting "file already closed" error on ioreader and cant find image pushed into repo.

How to make this work?

NOTE: for smaller images, im not getting "file already closed" error, but not sure how to know if the image has been pushed or not.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the `time.Second*120` timeout value?

Comment: To see if an image has been successfully pushed, you could use this command: `docker pull docker.dummy.com/some/repo:some-tag`

Comment: @code_monk time out worked. But how to check if image is done pushing? i mean programatically..not using docker pull.

Comment: The code will simply return. The operation simply ends when it's done